# Is it the Saraswati in Brahma loka or her partial incarnation married to Matinara?

Tags: mahabharata, saraswati

The following passage says that *Saraswati appeared in person before the Matinara and chose him for husband*. The passage was narrated by Vaisampayana to Janamejaya

> And of her was born a son named Arihan. And Arihan took to wife
>   Sudeva, the princess of Anga, and upon her he begat a son named
>   Riksha. And Riksha married Jwala, the daughter of Takshaka, and he
>   begat upon her a son of the name of **Matinara, who performed on the
>   bank of Saraswati the twelve years' sacrifice said to be so
>   efficacious. On conclusion of the sacrifice, Saraswati appeared in
>   person before the king and chose him for husband.** And he begat upon
>   her a son named Tansu. Here occurs a sloka descriptive of Tansu's
>   descendants.
>
> "**Tansu was born of Saraswati by Matinara**. And Tansu himself begat a
>   son named Ilina on his wife, the princess Kalingi.
>
> [[SECTION XCV, Sambhava Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01096.htm)

Is it the goddess [Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saraswati), the wife of Brahma or the Saraswati, the goddess associated with the [river Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarasvati_River) married to Matinara?

***Note***: [Answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/what-is-the-relation-of-saraswati-vak-with-the-river-saraswati-and-trinity-or) says that Saraswati, the goddess associated with the river Saraswati is either a partial or full incarnation of the wife of Brahma. If full incarnation, then both will be the same. Else, who married to Matinara? Full or partial incarnation of Saraswati?

Comment: Some scholars say the Saraswati river mentioned in Rig Veda has many meanings.  Apart from indicating the river, the name Saraswati was used as an epithet, but not the wife of Brahma.  In Puranas and interpolated versions of Mahabharata it was described differently.   Ganga was described at places as the wife of Shiva and she was made the wife of Santanu in Mahabharata. @hanugm