# Which is correct wrt to Saraswati river? Did it flow from Haryana to Gujarat or did it meet Ganga and Yamuna at Triveni Sangam in Prayagraj?

Tags: saraswati, rivers

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23551/19725 - acc to this answer Saraswati goes from Haryana to Gujarat. But Triveni Sangam is said to be the confluence point of Ganga Yamuna and Saraswati.

Which of them is true?